# how to php loop inside an existing foreach for joined SQL tables

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, join, foreach

I am currently stuck attempting to understand how I loop results inside an existing loop using SQL results from joined tables.

Firstly, here is my current code:

```
<?php
include('OrderCore/connect-db.php');
$POIds = array();
if ($result = $mysqli->query("SELECT ProductionOrderID FROM ProductionOrder" ) ) {
    while ($row = $result->fetch_object()) {
        $POIds[] = $row->ProductionOrderID;
    }
}
foreach ( $POIds as $index => $OrderId ) {
    if ( $result = $mysqli->query("
    SELECT * 
    FROM ProductionOrder AS p
    LEFT JOIN ProductionOrderStatus AS s ON ( p.ProductionOrderID = s.ProductionOrderStatusID ) 
    LEFT JOIN NotGood AS n ON ( p.ProductionOrderID = n.NGID ) 
    LEFT JOIN BatchOrder AS b ON ( p.ProductionOrderID = b.ProductionOrderID)
    LEFT JOIN Brand AS bd ON ( p.ProductionOrderID = bd.BrandID ) 
    LEFT JOIN CustomerOrder AS co ON ( p.ProductionOrderID = co.COID ) 
    LEFT JOIN Customer AS c ON ( p.ProductionOrderID = c.CustomerID ) 
    LEFT JOIN CustomerOrderStatus AS cos ON ( p.ProductionOrderID = cos.COStatusID )
    WHERE p.ProductionOrderID='$OrderId'") ) {
        while( $row = $result->fetch_object() ) {
            print "<h1>Order: $OrderId</h1>";
            print "<table class='table table-striped'>";
            print "<tr> <th>PO ID</th> <th>PO #</th> <th>Order Quantity</th> <th>Balance Left</th> <th>Production Date</th> <th>Production Order Status</th> <th>Not Good ID</th> </tr>";
            print "<td>" . $row->ProductionOrderID . "</td>";
            print "<td>" . $row->PONum . "</td>";
            print "<td>" . $row->OrderQTY . "</td>";
            print "<td>" . $row->BalLeftNum . "</td>";
            print "<td>" . $row->ProductionDate . "</td>";
            print "<td>" . $row->ProductionOrderStatusID . "</td>";
            print "<td>" . $row->NGID . "</td>";
            print "</tr>";
            print "</table>";
            //BatchOrder
            print "<table class='table table-striped'>";
            print "<tr> <th>Batch ID</th> <th>Brand Name</th> <th>Batch Quantity</th> <th>Availability Date</th> <th>Remaining Balance</th> <th>Production Order ID</th> </tr>";
            print "<td>" . $row->BatchID . "</td>";
            print "<td>" . $row->BrandID . "</td>";
            print "<td>" . $row->BatchQTY . "</td>";
            print "<td>" . $row->AvailDate . "</td>";
            print "<td>" . $row->RemainBal . "</td>";
            print "<td>" . $row->ProductionOrderID . "</td>";
            print "</tr>";
            print "</table>";
            //CustomerOrder
            print "<table class='table table-striped'>";
            print "<tr> <th>Customer ID</th> <th>Customer Name</th> <th>Invoice Quantity</th> <th>Invoice #</th> <th>Shipping Date</th> <th>Batch ID</th> <th>CO Status</th> </tr>";
            print "<td>" . $row->COID . "</td>";
            print "<td>" . $row->CustomerID . "</td>";
            print "<td>" . $row->InvoiceQTY . "</td>";
            print "<td>" . $row->InvoiceNum . "</td>";
            print "<td>" . $row->ShipDate . "</td>";
            print "<td>" . $row->BatchID . "</td>";
            print "<td>" . $row->COStatusID . "</td>";
            print "</tr>";
            print "</table>";
        }
    }
    else
    {
        print "No results to display!";
    }
}
$mysqli->close();
?>
```

This code currently produces this result: https://i.stack.imgur.com/FdCJL.png.
This is almost the correct, intended behaviour... Each `ProductionOrderID` should generate a new table which has 2 child tables: `BatchOrder` and `CustomerOrder`. But it's currently only showing 1 result for each child table.

So to clarify, there can be any number of `ProductionOrder`s created by the user (hence the `foreach` looping through the array). Each `ProductionOrder` can contain: Zero, One or Many `BatchOrder`s and each `BatchOrder` can contain: Zero, One or Many `CustomerOrder`s.

**The current issue:**
As per the screenshot link just above, it is only displaying 1 `BatchOrder` and 1 `CustomerOrder` per `ProductionOrder`. My sample data contains multiple Batch Orders for `ProductionOrderID=1` but they aren't displaying.

I am not sure if the issue is partly PHP and partly SQL related. I am new to both languages but I suspect `LEFT JOIN` is incorrect. However, it was the only method (currently) to display each `ProductionOrder` correctly with a `BO` and `CO` each... Just not all of them. I also suspect I need to execute another loop inside my existing while loop but I'm not sure on the correct approach as my current attempts have all been unsuccessful.

**Detailed Information**
Here is a copy of my database SQL with sample data: https://pastebin.com/A3rt8kX4

Also my ERD to show intended behaviour: https://i.stack.imgur.com/5nlJu.png

Any help to not just help solve this current issue but to help me understand why it's wrong is absolutely appreciated.

---

**EDIT: 1**
I have fixed the keys joined in my SELECT statement but now only see one PO:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/p5b8s.png

```
SELECT * 
FROM ProductionOrder AS p
INNER JOIN ProductionOrderStatus AS s ON ( p.ProductionOrderID = s.ProductionOrderID ) 
INNER JOIN NotGood AS n ON ( p.ProductionOrderID = n.ProductionOrderID ) 
INNER JOIN BatchOrder AS b ON ( p.ProductionOrderID = b.ProductionOrderID )
INNER JOIN Brand AS bd ON ( b.BatchID = bd.BatchID ) 
INNER JOIN CustomerOrder AS co ON ( b.BatchID = co.BatchID ) 
INNER JOIN Customer AS c ON ( co.COID = c.COID ) 
INNER JOIN CustomerOrderStatus AS cos ON ( co.COID = cos.COID )
WHERE p.ProductionOrderID='$OrderId'") ) {
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to join the primary key to the corresponding foreign key, for example:

```
LEFT JOIN ProductionOrderStatus AS s ON ( p.ProductionOrderID = s.ProductionOrderStatusID )
```

should be

```
LEFT JOIN ProductionOrderStatus AS s ON ( p.ProductionOrderID = s.ProductionOrderID )
```

You have the same issue in most of your joins.

Comment: Cheers for providing an example, I have corrected my SELECT statement. However, now I only see one iteration of the `ProductionOrderID` and still just 1 iteration of both the `BatchOrder` and `CustomerOrder`s